# How to fire 'object:selected' without mouse clicking?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm working on fabric js canvas. I need to fire `'object:selected'` without clicking on the object or the canvas. I tried to call the following:

```
canvas._handleEvent('mouse:down','object:selected', Myobject);
```

In which I tried to manually set the received event as `'mouse:down'` and the event to fire as `'object:selected'`. But it says `"canvas._handleEvent is not a function"`. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: `"canvas._handleEvent is not a function"` means there is no such a function called `_handleEvent` existing on `canvas`

Comment: @Dummy Right!! but according to Fabric js documentation [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html), it's a canvas method.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.on('object:selected', function(e) {
  alert('object:selected fired');
});
canvas.trigger('object:selected');
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas tabindex="1" id="canvas" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
```

More Information: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events.